# jenkins downstream jobs not triggering

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

I have a large multi-module maven project, which is handled by a number of jobs in jenkins.
I have noticed that not all downstream jobs are trggered when an upstream job finishes successfully. The upstream and downstream jobs are calcualated automatically by Jenkins.  Sometimes a subset of the jobs are triggered, and sometimes none. This puzzles me, any good explanations out there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the category better late than never:

There was a bug in the maven job code which would ignore triggers if upstream dependencies were still building :

see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21903

this was fixed end september 2014, so any relatively recent version should no longer be affected by this.